# Codeigniter: Can I send email using codeigniter email library with a POP account

Tags: email, codeigniter

I am a novice at this email sending task. I have a pop account on my company's mail network. Can I send email with this account using the default email library in codeigniter. 
Some code references will be thoroughly helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Email Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) - supports mail, sendmail and SMTP protocols.